# How to connect SAP * platform with GitHub?

Tags: github, sap-cloud-platform, sap-web-ide, sap-business-application-studio

Is it possible to connect <del>*Hana Cloud Platform* (HCP)</del> <del>*SAP Cloud Platform* (SCP)</del> SAP Business Technology Platform (SAP-BTP) with GitHub?

We want to use GitHub as the repository for our Fiori applications instead of <del>SCP</del> SAP-BTP git on-premise.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily clone GitHub Repositories in SAP Business Application Studio just like in any other IDE.

Here are some blog posts:

https://blogs.sap.com/2020/10/03/working-with-github-in-sap-business-application-studio-next-generation-of-sap-web-ide/

https://blogs.sap.com/2021/02/11/how-to-connect-your-corporate-github-to-sap-business-application-studio/